# Always getting response as Invalid Session Token in soap client php

Tags: php, web-services, wsdl, soapui, soap-client

I have php version 7.1 in my localhost. I have made changes in my php.ini file to run SOAP from my localhost.

I need to generate primary and secondary session token by passing login id and password to SOAP client API.

Once session token is authenticated it will return some rate chart. My code is generating session tokens. But when I am passing that token key to the next method in SOAP Client api its always giving me an error like "Invalid Session Token" or "Invalid Authentication". However the same tokens are working well in SOAP UI exe. I mean I have installed SOAP UI exe and by using wsdl "http://cnx.test.dat.com:9280/wsdl/TfmiFreightMatching.wsdl" and using method "Login" and "LookupRate" its working everything fine. The way i need that.

But whenever i am using that tokens in php localhost its always giving me an authentication error by SOAP Client.

I am sharing my code below.

```
$wsdl = "http://cnx.test.dat.com:9280/wsdl/TfmiFreightMatching.wsdl";

$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array('trace' => true));
$params = array('loginOperation'=>array('loginId'=>'ryder_cnx1','password'=>'ryder1','thirdPartyId'=>'dl'));

$client->Login($params);

$data = $client->__getLastResponse();

$p = xml_parser_create();
xml_parse_into_struct($p, $data, $vals, $index);
xml_parser_free($p);

$token = [];

foreach ($vals as $key => $value) {
   foreach ($value as $key1 => $value1) {
      if($key1 == "value")
         $token[] = $value1;  
   }
}

echo "Primary Token = ".$token[0];
echo "<br> Secondary Token = ".$token[1];
//echo "<br> Expiry Date = ".$token[2];

$params_session = array("sessionToken"=> array("primary"=>$token[0], "secondary"=>$token[1]));

$namespace = 'http://www.tcore.com/TcoreTypes.xsd'; // I am not sure about this namespace. Whether its correct or not.

$header = new SoapHeader($namespace,'sessionHeader',$params_session,true);
$client->__setSoapHeaders($header);                                           

$params_data = array('lookupRateOperations'=> array(
                                 'equipment'=>'Vans',
                                            'origin'=>array('postalCode'=>array('country'=>'US','code'=>'30004')),
                                            'destination'=>array('postalCode'=>array('country'=>'US','code'=>'10001'))
                ));

try{
   $result =   $client->LookupRate($params_data);      

     print_r($result);

}catch (SoapFault $exception){
      //or any other handling you like
      print_r(get_class($exception));
      enter code hereprint_r($exception);
}
```

if anybody have any idea, please share it with me.

Awaiting any response.

Thanks a lot in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is very old, and most likely the OP figured it out.  But in case anyone else comes along, I was able to get it working with two slight changes.

First,

```
$namespace = 'http://www.tcore.com/TcoreTypes.xsd';
```

Should be

```
$namespace = 'http://www.tcore.com/TcoreHeaders.xsd';
```

Second,

```
$params_session = array("sessionToken"=> array("primary"=>$token[0], "secondary"=>$token[1]));
```

should be

```
$params_session = array(
    "sessionToken"=> array(
        "primary"=>base64_decode($token[0]),
        "secondary"=>base64_decode($token[1])
    )
);
```

The rest of my code is similar enough that if the above changes are made, it should work.  I would also refrain from posting real usernames and passwords, btw.